# adding opencv library onto node-gyp bindings.gyp

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

Im trying to connect the opencv library to my node C++ addon. Im using windows and I have downloaded opencv and extracted it. I added it to my project directory like below:

```
|   app.js
|   binding.gyp
|
+---.vscode
|       c_cpp_properties.json
|
+---build
|       config.gypi
|
+---c
|       test.cc
|       opencv.cc
|
\---libs
    \---opencv
         \---more files
```

I want to use the opencv library in my opencv.cc file but I cant find a way to include it as anyway I've tried has produced errors.

Ive looked into adding the lib file but I got errors when gyp tried to read the file and gave out about unknown symbols.

When trying to add a header file that includes other header files i then run into a relative pathing issue as the headers seem to use relative but from what it looks like the compilation of gyp seems to use an absoloute path.
My binding.gyp is where the issue is but I cant figure it out.Any help would be appreciated!
The binding.gyp file itself

```
{
    "targets" : [
        {
            "target_name" : "opencvTest",
            "sources" : ["./c/opencv.cc"],
            "include_dirs": [ "C:/Users/test/Desktop/nodeCExample/libs/opencv/build/include/opencv2/" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The output error:

```
c:\users\test\desktop\nodecexample\libs\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp(48): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\c
\opencv.cc) [C:\Users\test\Desktop\nodeCExample\build\opencvTest.vcxproj]
```